# Get micro frontend dynamic loaded module URL inside the module?

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend

Before to move to "library: { type: "module" }", we have got the URL from here:

```
const myScript: any = document.currentScript || document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
const baseUrl = new URL(myScript.src).origin + '/';
```

Now is the document.currentScript null and document.scripts does not contain the loaded scripts and they are in some "webpackChunk{moduleName}" variable.

How to get from where is the script(module) loaded, inside the script?

(import.meta.url gives file:// address of the script. What we need is the imported module URL.  loadRemoteModule is dynamic)

Comment: I'm slightly curious as to why you would need this. However, I would expect import.meta to be correct (for a production build)?

Comment: @MikeOne The imported modules are applications (docker containers) with their own services and they are called from the modules. What gives import.meta.url is file:///src/src/..../services/base.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here:
[Disable compile time evaluation of import.meta.url](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/15246)

There is a new flag in webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    parser: {
        javascript: {importMeta: false}
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Now the  import.meta.url will be evaluated at runtime. Sorry that I have posted an answer, but I have searched the Internet for two days. May be this will spare some time for someone. :)